# Custom Django login, can not compare passwords

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python. I read the docs and the standard login system does not look good for me as I want to use email and password for user login.

So, I created a new app, with view and model.

Here is my login function.

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        usermail = request.POST['usermail']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()

        if usermail == '' or password == '':
            error = u'All fields should be filled'
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error})

        try:
            sql = "SELECT * FROM users_users WHERE userMail=usermail"
            user = str(Users.objects.raw(sql)[0])
            userInfo = user.split(',')
            if userInfo[2] = password:
                return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': userInfo}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                error = u'Email or password is not valid'
                return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        except:
            error = u'User with an email %s does not exist' %usermail
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': error}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render(request, 'login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem happens when I try to to compare passwords from the database and user provided password.

Model for the view:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    """
    This class is used for user authorization
    """

    userName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    userMail = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    userPass = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    userRole = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='user')

    def __unicode__(self):
        # return self.userPass
        return u'%s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.userName, self.userMail, self.userPass, self.userRole)
```

Comment: What problem happens?

Comment: Little Bobby Tables. That's what happens :)

Comment: I am new to python and django, but not to programming at all, so here I just wanted to get a pass from a database, without any manipulating with security.

Comment: This question is so wrong on so many levels, like all the "PHP best practices" put to work at the same time. I will see nightmares of this code, please please look into the existing Django auth system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DO NOT DO THIS**. Django has a perfectly good and fully documented system for [replacing the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/) while keeping the authentication system, which has had several years to be tested for security vulnerabilities. Yours is not at all secure and you should not try to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You **shouldn't** reinvented the wheel. Instead of making your own login system, with your own user class, you should [customize the current User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/) which allows to add field and validation methods.

By creating your own system, you can make security hole in your application and you're losing one of the power of Django: its user management and the well admin auto generated!

Comment: @Jay: Yeah, the son I ever wanted :D